# How to create a dynamic hybrid app using visual studio

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app, apache-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 in windows 8. i created simple app using Apache cordova in visual studio .so i want to create app ,i am really confused . In native app we take data through web-services and save it in local app database in the time when we start the app . then we use the data for by fetching  from local database in app .but in hybrid app i do not have any idea. In apache cordova i seen a plugin sqlite storage plugin. but i do not know what is its use and also i heard about Ajax. In my hand i have stored database and its webservice with data.so what are the ways to show use dynamic data in a hybrid app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but in hybrid app i do not have any idea. In apache cordova i seen a plugin sqlite storage plugin. but i do not know what is its use and also i heard about Ajax.

You can get data from your web-service through Ajax.You can write your own functions of Ajax using [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). If you are using certain frameworks, please check if there is a wrapper for Ajax in that framework.(e.g. [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) of AngularJS). You can use the wrapper to simplify your codes.

After retrieving the data, you can save the data to mobile SQLite database through [cordova-plugin-SQLite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage). Currently, most of the mobiles use SQLite for data storage.

Comment: i tried ajax but it is not working can u help me .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759308/get-xml-data-using-ajax-failed